# call jquery click function from other page

Tags: php, jquery

Can i get variable if my button from other file..
example page 1 (a.php):

```
<a href="#" class="mybutton">Button</a>
```

and page 2 (b.php):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.php .mybutton').click(function() {
    alert("ok"); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Without talking about clicking buttons on different pages, can you explain what you're trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: well im use bootstrap table.. but i call data from json (page 2). then i want to click hyperlink i made from json page.. but it not work on my main page (page 1).

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but maybe look at [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)? `$('a.php.btnadd').trigger('click');`.

Comment: yeah,, can i do that ? i think my code was wrong..

Answer (score 0):

If you put your function in an external js file then you can fire it from any page. then it wont be a click function but a regular js function. Refernce the js file at the bottom of any page where you want to use the function.